# Pixastic blurfast easing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pixastic

Is it possible to apply easing to a pixastic blurfast function?

I have a full screen background image that I would like to blur upon clicking a button as I overlay some more content on top of it.

I am currently doing this (using jquery):

```
$(".bg").pixastic("blurfast", {amount:1});
```

Which works fine for the blurring but it happens instantly. Is it possible to make this effect fade in with some kind of easing?

I have done this effect before in Flash but this is my first attempt in javascript.

I am open to using a different js library if it is possible in something other than pixastic

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible?  Sure.

Just like it is possible to do easing on pretty much any numerical value... the problem is that pixastic doesn't directly support the easing, so you are looking at building the easing function yourself, which is pretty easy.

Once you have the easing function built (which I am not going to try to write for you as there are numerous easing functions, and I have no idea what type of effect you are looking for), just feed the resulting blur value into pixastic.

for example, create a function like this:

```
function myEasingFunc(percent){

    // Your easing code here

    return result;
}
```

Then call this function repeatedly with incremented values for percent:

```
for(i==0;i<100;i++){
   var amount=myEasingFunc(i);
   $("#myimage").pixastic("blurfast", {amount:amount});
}
```

Obviously, this would not be what you would directly want, as there is no delay between the steps, and having 100 steps of 1% increment each is wasteful, but it is illustrative of the process.

The options go on and on... rather that make the percentage of blur based on time, like you are thinking, you could also have it based on the position of text that flies into the box from beyond view, just as one example.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I hope it helps someone, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Approach we are using it something like this:

```
var wrap  = $(parent_element);
var img = wrap.find('.img-to-blur');
var canvas = img.clone().addClass('blur').css('opacity', '').prependTo(wrap);

img.fadeOut();
canvas.fadeIn();
```

It's nice to the CPU than recalculating each blur level in javascript.

NOTICE: the code is more of a pseudo-code, it may not be CTRL+INSERT & SHIFT+INSERT ready.